# Calculate surface by logarithmic function?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, mathematics

Is there any way to use the `log()` function in order to calculate the surface of a mesh?

Answer (score 5):

**math.log(x)**

Yes you can use the `log` method in the XYZ surface, just have to remember that `log(x)` will throw a math domain error for any value of `x` less than or equal to zero.

[image]
*Bad Example using helper method `a = log(u) if u < 0 else 0` the equations are `x(u, v) = u, y(u, v) = a, z(u, v) = 1`*

Unfortunately the minima of u and v can not be set greater than zero.  To set a range for say `u` to `[1, 2]` could set up a helper method `b = u + 1` and use `b` for `u`. Similarly for `v`

Comment: thanks for the good answer. Is it possible for you to show me how to 360° rotate this function in a script? Or is it maybe not that simple? Thanks a lot for your help!! Felix

Comment: "Rotating" in 90 degree increments will be akin to swapping formulas for  x y and z.