# Z Function Surface log syntax

Tags: mesh

What do you type into Z Math Surface to get the function of log (x).

I tried 'log x' and 'log(x)' with no success.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109533/calculate-surface-by-logarithmic-function

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that the surface is evaluated over positive and negative values, and `log` is undefined for negative values. If you look in the console, you'll see that when you use `log` in your equation (for instance: `log(x)+log(y)`, you'll get the following error:
[image]

If you square the values of x and y, though, there will be no negative values and the equation works:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 7):

**Shift the domain.**

As explained the domain of `log(x)` is for `x > 0`  [Related using XYZ surface and setting a default when undefined](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/109536/15543)

$\log(x)$ is asymptotic towards x = 0. *ie*

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \log(x) = -\infty$$

If the equation `z = 0` is used the domain of x and y used by the operator is [-1, 1], (default size 2, 2)  hence can shift to x, y > 0 domain by replacing

```
x with x + 1.00001
y with  y + 1.00001
```

or taking operator size property into account, `x` has the domain `[-x_size / 2, x_size / 2]`

So to plot `log(x) * log(y)` on size 10 * 20, on the positive x, y quadrant use

```
log(x + 5.00001) * log(y + 10.00001)
```

*May wish to move the resulting mesh, in EDIT mode by selecting all and shifting 5.00001 in x and 10.00001 in y, such that the mesh origin (0, 0, 0) is x, y origin*